# Не определена системная переменная

Tags: php

Вопрос по PHP: на локальном компьютере под Apache работает получение IP адреса, переменная `$REMOTE_ADDR`, а на реальном сервере - пустые значения в переменной.

Comment: pav_velux, не нужно тратить очки. достаточно просто принять ответ как верный (галочка около ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте 
`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`